# How do I close and reopen session for http post in xcode? 

Tags: xcode, http, asp-classic

We are sending http posts to an asp URL from our Xcode project. Since we are only able to send one post "per session" we need to be able to close the http connection after each post then reopen to send another.

How can we close the http post and then reopen it to send another?

Comment: you can try stop the processing of your page using **response.end** to stop the execution of asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Session.Abandon() in your asp code after processing the post. This way the session will be closed after this request and not linger for 20 minutes( or whatever is set as default session duration)